# Indicate space for gsub replacement

Tags: r, replace, gsub, space

I am new to R and I've been looking around on here already and found some answers but they did not work for me.
With gsub I want to replace some companies' names for a topic model.
An example

I got  `text <- gsub(pattern = "abc AG", replacement = " ", x = text, ignore.case = TRUE)` 
Now I also want to have abc without the AG replaced but since abc also appears in some words I cannot simply remove it. So how do I remove [space]abc[space].

I tried it with [[:space:]], \\s etc. but none of them would work. Maybe I inserted them wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a boundary like `\\babc\\b`

Answer (score 1):

" abc " will not work in your example. Simply because you don't have a space before "abc" and only after.

One thing you could try is to do two replacements in a row, removing first "AG ", and then "abc ".

```
vtext <- c("abc AG zoo", "abc foo", "abc bar")
sub(" abc ", "", vtext) #don't work
# [1] "abc AG zoo" "abc foo"    "abc bar" 

sub("abc ", "", vtext) #works
# [1] "AG zoo" "foo"    "bar"

# So you can have somthing like
sub("abc ", "", sub("AG ", "", vtext))
#[1] "zoo" "foo" "bar"
```